# Retrieving data from a class without the str method

Tags: python, python-2.7

I posses a class called `Collatz` and a function `collatz_it` which creates an object of the class, I'm trying to generate the number of steps for a number to reach 1 using the [collatz conjucture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture) and their corresponding steps till 1 million using a generator

```
import collatz
values = {}
count = 0
#collatz.collatz_it(n)

def gen():
    n = 0
    x = 0
    while True:
        yield x
        n += 1
        x = collatz.collatz_it(n)

for i in gen():
    count += 1
    values[count] = i
    print values
    if count == 1000000:
        break
```

As you can see, I generate the amount of steps taken for it to reach 1 using the collatz conjecture for a number given and add it to a dictionary with the corresponding number **but** when I print out the dictionary values, it's output is awkwardly something like this:

```
{1: 0}
{1: 0, 2: <collatz.Collatz instance at 0x01DCA580>}
{1: 0, 2: <collatz.Collatz instance at 0x01DCA580>, 3: <collatz.Collatz instance at 0x01DCDF58>}
{1: 0, 2: <collatz.Collatz instance at 0x01DCA580>, 3: <collatz.Collatz instance at 0x01DCDF58>, 4: <collatz.Collatz instance at 0x01DCDFA8>}
{1: 0, 2: <collatz.Collatz instance at 0x01DCA580>, 3: <collatz.Collatz instance at 0x01DCDF58>, 4: <collatz.Collatz instance at 0x01DCDFA8>, 5: <collatz.Collatz instance at 0x01DCDEB8>}
{1: 0, 2: <collatz.Collatz instance at 0x01DCA580>, 3: <collatz.Collatz instance at 0x01DCDF58>, 4: <collatz.Collatz instance at 0x01DCDFA8>, 5: <collatz.Collatz instance at 0x01DCDEB8>, 6: <collatz.Collatz instance at 0x01DCDE90>}
{1: 0, 2: <collatz.Collatz instance at 0x01DCA580>, 3: <collatz.Collatz instance at 0x01DCDF58>, 4: <collatz.Collatz instance at 0x01DCDFA8>, 5: <collatz.Collatz instance at 0x01DCDEB8>, 6: <collatz.Collatz instance at 0x01DCDE90>, 7: <collatz.Collatz instance at 0x01DE8940>}
```

If I print `print i` instead of `print values` I get the required output, this is basically because the `print` statement triggers the `__str__` method in the class

Isn't there any way I could add the actual steps to the dictionary without entering `<collatz.Collatz instance at 0x01DCDFA8>` , Is there any sort of method of retrieving data as from a `__str__` method so that my dictionary looks something like this:

```
{1: 0}
{1: 0, 2: 1}
{1: 0, 2: 1, 3: 7}
```

Comment: Why can't you use `__str__`? Or `__repr__` for that matter?

Comment: The default representation of any Python container is to use the `repr()` output of the contents, not `str()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default representation of any Python container is to use the `repr()` output of the contents, not `str()`.

The solution would be for you to either give the `collatz.Collatz()` instance a `__repr__` method (you can monkey-patch that in), or to use a subclass of `dict` that uses `str()` instead of `repr()` when displaying the contents.

Monkey-patching in a `__repr__` could be as simple as:

```
collatz.Collatz.__repr__ = collatz.Collatz.__str__
```

Of course, if this is your *own* code, just define a `__repr__` method in the class body itself.

Comment: ...or even simpler: `collatz.Collatz.__repr__ = lambda x: str(x)`

Comment: or `X.__repr__ = X.__str__` ;) But what's the point of monkey patching their own class?

Comment: @thg435: I was assuming it was not their own.

Comment: @Aya or `collatz.Collatz.__repr__ = str`

Comment: @Marcin I tried that, but it doesn't actually work for some reason.

Comment: @Marcin: No, built-in functions cannot be used as methods. They lack the descriptor protocol (`.__get__()`) required to make that work.

Comment: never knew a special method as __repr__ exist, Thanks @MartijnPieters. Does anyone know a place where I can get more on special methods

Answer (score 0):

Use a class which inherits from `dict` and has its own `__repr__` which does what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Store the value that you want on this line:

`values[count] = i`

Do something like

`values[count] = i.value`

or

`values[count] = str(i)`

In the last case this assumed that you have written a `__str__` method for the class:

```
class Collatz:
...
def __str__(self):
    return str(self.value)
```